# Xamarin Sending POST Data

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am attempting to send POST data to my server and get back a response.  For some reason, no POST data is actually getting sent.  A request is being sent to my server but the POST array is empty.

Here is my code for sending the request:

```
public class GlobalMethods
{
    public async Task<string> callAjax(string mthd,NameValueCollection parameters)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

        var result = await client.PostAsync("http://dev.adex-intl.com/adex/mvc/receiving/"+mthd, new StringContent(content)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var tokenJson = "";

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            tokenJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return tokenJson;
    }
}
```

And here is my code that calls the above method:

```
public void loginPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(badge.Text)) {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Enter your badge number", "Ok");
        } else {
            IsBusy = true;
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
            parameters["badgetNumber"] = badge.Text;
            GlobalMethods globalMethods = new GlobalMethods();
                var results = globalMethods.callAjax("login", parameters);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Also, I'm a newbie to Xamarin and C# so I'm not even sure if the way I am attempting to do things is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PostAsync for async sending data to server. your code should be something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "p1", "data1" },
   { "p2", "data2" }
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/index.php", content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specify the type of content that you want to send, in your case it's 'application/json', you can set it like that:
 "`var client = new HttpClient();
   var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters));
   content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");`". Also, I would suggest you to write code like that:

```
 var uri = new Uri(url);
 using (var body = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)))
 {
    body.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
       Version = new Version(1, 0),
       Content = body,
       Method = HttpMethod.Post,
       RequestUri = uri
    };

    try
    {
        using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request,cancellationToken))
        {
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
              //Deal with success response
           }
           else
           {
              //Deal with non-success response
           }               
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Deal with exception.
    }
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate the code.  I'll definitely give it a try since it seems to be a lot more robust than what I was trying to do.